# how can i get a specific value based on different criteria with vlookup?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel Workbook with two Sheets.

In one sheet I have these values:
[image: First sheet]

and in the second sheet there are these values:
[image: SecondSheet]

What I want is that in the Second sheet the cell E to have values of Prognose
from sheet 1 where **"Motor"** of *module_team* and "**OM470**" of *series* gives values based on *Datum_produktion* in the sheet 2.

The formula that I have tried till now is this but it doesn't seem to give me the values that I need.

`=IF(Tabelle1!B2="Motor";VLOOKUP(A2;Tabelle1!$F:$H;2;FALSE);VLOOKUP(A2;Tabelle1!$F:$H;2;FALSE))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the ones who have similar Trouble in the future, i used this Code and it helped me.
Use **Ctrl + Shift + Enter** and the Code will work.

````
=INDEX(Tabelle1!$E:$H;MATCH(1;(Tabelle1!$G:$G=A2)*(Tabelle1!$E:$E=E$1)*(Tabelle1!$B:$B="Motor");0);4)```
````

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP was designed for a single column of matching data. You need Tabelle1!B:B to match *motor*, Tabelle1!D:D to match E1 and Tabelle1!F:F to match A2. Put this in E2.

```
=INDEX(Tabelle1!$G:$G; AGGREGATE(15; 7; ROW($1:$999)/((Tabelle1!$D$1:$D$999=E$1)*(Tabelle1!$F$1:$F$999=$A2)*(Tabelle1!$B$1:$B$999="motor")); 1))
```

Adjust all the *999*'s to reflect the actual number of rows you have in the *Tabelle1* worksheet.

If you get that working, you should be able to copy the formula to G2, I2, K2, etc. then fill down for additional dates.

Comment: Thank you for the Reply, I adjusted the _999's_ for ther actual rows in the _Tabelle1_ but it gives me the _#NUM!_ in every line. In the Option Excel in Calculation part i checked the **Enable Iterative** calculation and still it wont Change the _#NUM!_ value.